# Error en servicio desde controller symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony3, symfony4

Estoy eliminando todo el código **deprecated** de mi aplicación en symfony 3.4 para pasarla a symfony 4, pero me he encontrado porblemas con el servicio de carga de archivos asociado a una entidad y que está implementado como lo explica la documentación oficial de symfony 3.4, y además revisando la documentación de symfony 4, la implementación es a consideración igual.
El error es el siguiente:

```
Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Services\FileUploader": argument "$targetDirectory" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.
```

$targetDirectory es la ruta donde se cargan los archivos en el servidor y está declarado como parámetro en el archivo app/config.

Realmente me quedan lagunas con el tema del autowiring en las clases, y al parecer es lo que me está fallando.

Esta es la declaración de la clase como servicio en el fichero service.yml del bundle:

```
services:    
    app.file_uploader:
        class: AppBundle\Services\FileUploader
        arguments: ['%ruta_ficheros_menaje%']
```

Esta es la implementación de la clase FileUploader:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Description of FileUploader
 *
 * @author IZQUIERDO
 */
class FileUploader {

    private $targetDirectory;

    public function __construct($targetDirectory) {
        $this->targetDirectory = $targetDirectory;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file) {
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

        try {
            $file->move($this->getTargetDirectory(), $fileName);
        } catch (FileException $e) {
            throw $e;
        }

        return $fileName;
    }

    public function getTargetDirectory() {
        return $this->targetDirectory;
    }

}
```

Y por último la implementacion de un EventListener sobre la entidad a la que se le asocia el archivo cargado:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\Fichero;
use AppBundle\Services\FileUploader;

/**
 * Description of MenajeFileUploadListener
 *
 * @author IZQUIERDO
 */
class MenajeFileUploadListener {

    private $uploader;

    public function __construct(FileUploader $uploader) {
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity instanceof Fichero) {
            return;
        }

        if ($fileName = $entity->getFileDoc()) {
            $ruta = $this->uploader->getTargetDirectory() . '/' . $fileName;
            if (file_exists($ruta)) {
                $entity->setFileDoc(new File($ruta));
            } else {
                $entity->setFileDoc(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity instanceof Fichero) {
            return;
        }

        if ($file = $entity->getFileDoc()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    private function uploadFile($entity) {
        // upload only works for Product entities
        if (!$entity instanceof Fichero) {
            return;
        }

        $file = $entity->getFileDoc();

        // only upload new files
        if ($file instanceof UploadedFile) {
            $fileName = $this->uploader->upload($file);
            $entity->setFileDoc($fileName);
        } elseif ($file instanceof File) {
            // prevents the full file path being saved on updates
            // as the path is set on the postLoad listener
            $entity->setFileDoc($file->getFilename());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución estuvo basada en que no es posible hacer autowiring sobre parámetros de tipo scalar pasados a una clase en su constructor. Para ello Symfony propone hacer **bind** y declarar este tipo de parámetro en el archivo app/services.yml bajo la entrada especial bind:
quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
services:
   _defaults:
       ....
   bind:
       targetDirectory: '%ruta_ficheros_mensje%'
   class: AppBundle/Services/FileUploader
   parámetros:
      $targetDirectory: '%targetDirectory%
```

'